# Devise Confirmable. How to remove email field?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, devise-confirmable

In order to send new confirmation instructions, an email has to be entered. I want to avoid that because my users are logged in at that moment, so there's no need for email asking. I just want to send new instructions to the `current_user.email`

I don't want to do client side stuff like this:

```
= f.email_field :email, value: current_user.email, class: "hidden"
```

I need a **server side** solution.

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with this:

First, override devise controller:

**config/routes.rb**

```rb
devise_for :users, controllers: { confirmations: "users/confirmations" }
```

**controllers/users/confirmations_controller.rb**

```rb
class Users::ConfirmationsController < Devise::ConfirmationsController
  def create
    redirect_to new_user_session_path unless user_signed_in?
    if current_user.confirmed?
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      current_user.send_confirmation_instructions
      redirect_to after_resending_confirmation_instructions_path_for(:user)
    end
  end
end

  protected

    # The path used after resending confirmation instructions.
    def after_resending_confirmation_instructions_path_for(resource_name)
      flash[:notice] = "Instructions sent successfully."            
      is_navigational_format? ? root_path (or whatever route) : '/'
    end    
end
```

Then remove the email field from the view.

**views/devise/confirmations/new.html.haml**

```rb
= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: confirmation_path(resource_name), method: :post }) do |f|
  = f.submit "Resend confirmation instructions"
```

Thanks everyone for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

As per the [devise codebase](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/9aa72db3656e6b0e84683f7dc8dad639415c78c0/lib/devise/models/confirmable.rb#L29), sending confirmation email can be invoked on a user as follows:

```
user = User.find(1)
user.send_confirmation_instructions
```

So you don't really need to get an email from the form.

Answer (score 0):

You have access to device method , this should work.

See the documentation [here](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/Devise/ConfirmationsController)

**routes.rb**

```
devise_for :users, controllers: { confirmations: "confirmations" }
```

**In view**

```
= link_to "resend confirmation", user_confirmation_path, data: { method: :post }
```